Reading contact_results creates algebraic loop
I have a working robot simulation in Drake. Now I want to output contact forces. ChatGPT and this post suggest:
const auto& contact_results = 
plant.get_contact_results_output_port().Eval<ContactResults<double>>(plant_context);

However, as soon as I introduce this line of code, Drake complains about an algebraic loop. I understand the concept of an algebraic loop but I am not feeding the values back into the system, I just want to cout them.
Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it?

Why do you think that chatgpt is more reliable than the the documentation ?

Because neither the tutorials in the documentation nor the class reference provide an example on how to do this, as using its search function with "get_contact_results_output_port" reveals.

I find this class MultibodyPlant (that's the one, right?) quite well documented. But sure, many things might still be unclear. Prepare https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and post the errors exactly as they appear, then definitely solution will come.

"I am not feeding the values back into the system" is an unclear statement. Are you doing the reading inside a system? (Presumably.) Do you do the reading related to the evaluation of an output port? That would be sufficient to trigger an algebraic loop (assuming that output value eventually connects to a plant input). As @pptaszni said, "minimal reproducible example" will go a long way towards getting you an answer.

I cannot disclose the code directly, I have to extract a minimal example which takes some time. I am going to report my progress and insights here, maybe somebody knows what's going on along the way.

Interestingly, it doesn't throw the exception right away. It runs a varying amount of time and then either I get the algebraic loop exception or just now even a segfault. My first thought was it happens when the meshcat visualization connects but it also happens without it.

I was able to run it until a contact happened. Nothing was reported but now it crashed with "double free or corruption (!prev)". There is definitely something else going on here :/

It does sound like you have a serious bug somewhere. Once you can reproduce your problem reliably, as @pptaszni  suggested, try to post a minimum reproduction example. That'll help some of us to analyze your problem.
That being said, probably a good excercise for you would be to create a toy example with an algebraic loop (not necessarily with an MbP) just to make sure your understanding of the concept matches the actual problem in Drake.

The inconsistent errors lead me to believe that some race condition is going on. And the system status query is actually called from another thread without any kind of mutex, that is probably the main problem here. I inherited the codebase and it worked like this so far... But I guess the Eval can clash with the other simulation thread. Now I put the reporting into a monitor lambda with systems::Simulator::set_monitor. There are still no contacts reported but at least it doesn't crash anymore.
(I am still working on the minimal example but I suspect this won't be necessary anymore)

The final issue was that I simulated hydroelastic contacts but tried to read point pair contacts. So the main problem was the multithreading. The really specific but really wrong exception that drake threw was absolutely misleading (which I don't mean as a complaint). It was also why I thought somebody who has experience with drake knows what's going on right away without me posting much code.

In the end the problem was that I tried to read the contact information from a different thread without mutexes or anything, so it had nothing to do with an algebraic loop.
The correct way to do it is from inside a monitor callback that gets executed every step.
